# PermGen space myeclipse

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory, myeclipse, permgen

I ran the `myeclipse` wizard MyEclipse/Scaffold Spring CRUD Application with artifact type "JPA Entities". Beforehand, I had added an entity class (just a basic `Pojo` with setters and getters, a id field annotated with @Id, and the class annotated with @Entity), start derby network server and then I always get this error:

```
a stack trace with "OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space".
```

I have tried starting myeclipse like this:

```
MEM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m";export MEM_ARGS
./myeclipse4spring
and like this
./myeclipse4spring -Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

and also by right clicking in `myeclipse4spring` on MyEclipse Tomcat and choosing Manage Launch Configuration/Add and then typing in:

```
-XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
```

in the magically appearing textbox but when I hit Enter everything vanish and the Ok button is grayed. Is there anybody out there who have got this wizard to work? I'm running Linux Mint.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? In the MyEclipse error log, the Tomcat console or in the Derby network server? By the way, MyEclipse4Spring memory settings are best done in the myeclipse4spring.ini file, which is in the specific installation folder, same as the myeclipse4spring executable.

Comment: I was getting it in the Tomcat console. It's solved now. The problem was I hadn't started Derby from inside Eclipse